# Which compression algorithm is better suited to compress protocol buffers output?

Tags: compression, protocol-buffers

Given:

- a DB table with numeric statistics only
- binary dump of the table - record after record
- protocol buffers dump of the table - using proto schema created from the table schema

As I have expected the binary dump produced by the protocol buffers is smaller than the naive binary dump of the same table:

```
PS Z:\dev\internal\vedtool> dir net_endshapes_stat.data | % { "$($_.Name): $($_.Length)B" }
net_endshapes_stat.data: 2941331B
net_endshapes_stat.data: 4311042B
```

However, when I compressed both files with 7z using Ultra level and LZMA method, I have discovered that the larger file compresses better:

```
PS Z:\dev\internal\vedtool> dir net_endshapes_stat.7z | % { "$($_.Name): $($_.Length)B" }
net_endshapes_stat.7z: 1206186B
net_endshapes_stat.7z: 1055901B
```

Now, I understand that it is completely OK, still I am wondering whether there is a compression algorithm better tuned to perform on the protocol buffers output.

**EDIT**

Here is the proto schema:

```
message net_endshapes_stat {
  optional fixed32 timestamp = 1;
  optional sint32 shape_id = 2;
  optional sint64 bps_in = 3;
  optional sint64 bps_out = 4;
  optional sint64 total_in = 5;
  optional sint64 total_out = 6;
}
```

Comment: What are the data-types in the .proto?

Comment: Here you go. If you want so, I can even send you the files themselves :-)

Comment: Interesting. I've seen a few similar cases before. Ultimately, compression depends **hugely** on the data...

Comment: Is there anything to do?

Comment: actually, I would be very tempted to try a "packed array" in protobuf; in particular, a varint doesn't care whether it is implementing a sint32 or a sint64, so I would try: `repeated sint64 values = 2 [packed=true];`, and unpick the elements manually. Worth a try.

Comment: Is `repeated sint64 values = 2 [packed=true]` interchangeable with `optional sint32 shape_id = 2;optional sint64 bps_in = 3;optional sint64 bps_out = 4;optional sint64 total_in = 5;optional sint64 total_out = 6;` ?

Comment: you mean for existing data? no; it is not wire compatible; instead of `[field 2, varint][payload][field 3, varint][payload]...[field 6, varint][payload]` it is `[field 2, string][length][5 varints back to back, no headers]`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not suit me.

Comment: then.... all I can suggest is one of: absorb (live with) the extra 150k; try a few other compressions (gzip, deflate) to see if it behaves better under those; or use the alternative format

Comment: I am not suprised, Protocol Buffers is basically removing leading x'00' bytes from numbers + adding tags to the file. The compression programs do an excellent job of compressing repeating bytes (i.e x'00000009' has 3 leading x'00' bytes in it.

Comment: Not exactly. It also removes all the default values. In my case zeroes, lots of zeroes. Note, the uncompressed sizes - pb has removed more than 1M. Yet it is larger after the compression.